# How to get salary back from with max(datetime) aggreate?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Simple table:

```
create table [dbo].[payraisehistory]
(
    [id][int] not null,
    [payrate][money] not null,
    [empid][int] not null
)
```

// Query to return last payrate raise

```
select prh.empid,  max(prh.dategrant)
from payraisehistory prh
group by prh.empid

empid   (No column name)
2   2013-07-30 00:00:00.000
3   2013-07-30 00:00:00.000
```

How can I get the pay back as well....when I add the what the payrate was I get back all rows instead of the latest pay rate (per max(dategrant).

I want to do this without using nested queries.  What am I missing with the group by?

```
select prh.empid, prh.payrate, max(prh.dategrant)
from payraisehistory prh
group by prh.empid, payrate

empid   payrate (No column name)
2   20.00   2013-04-30 00:00:00.000
2   30.00   2013-05-30 00:00:00.000
2   40.00   2013-06-30 00:00:00.000
2   50.00   2013-07-30 00:00:00.000
3   100.00  2013-04-30 00:00:00.000
3   120.00  2013-07-30 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where you want to use `row_number()`:

```
select prh.empid, prh.payrate, prh.dategrant
from (select prh.*,
             row_number() over (partition by prh.empid order by prh.dategrant desc) as seqnum
      from payraisehistory prh
     ) prh
where seqnum = 1;
```

Your query is:

```
select prh.empid, prh.payrate, max(prh.dategrant)
from payraisehistory prh
group by prh.empid, payrate;
```

This is aggregating by `empid` *and* `payrate`.  These seem to uniquely define the rows in your table, so you are getting all of them back.  I suppose a payrate could be repeated, but your data does not have such an instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    select prh.empid, prh.payrate, CASE WHEN prh.dategrant =  max(prh.dategrant) over(partition
    by prh.empid ORDER BY byprh.empid) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS st from payraisehistory prh
) AS T WHERE t.st = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Running a max(payrate) may give you the pay rate from a different record from max(dategrant).  You will need to get the record id of the last date, and pull the payrate from that record in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table to itself using the `MAX` aggregate in a subquery:

```
select p.empid, p.payrate, p.dategrant
from payraisehistory p
    join (
        select prh.empid,  max(prh.dategrant) maxdategrant
        from payraisehistory prh
        group by prh.empid
    ) p2 on p.empid = p2.empid and p.dategrant = p2.maxdategrant
```

Comment: double scan table! OVER CLAUSE opportunity came in SQL SERVER 2005.

Comment: @realnumber3012 -- completely agree -- using a `ranking function` would be a better solution for this RDBMS.